# сравнение строк в dart

Tags: строки, dart

Как узнать какая строка больше abc или acb в dart?
Типа этого:

```
if("abc">"acb"){
   print("");
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

С этим вроде неплохо справляется `compareTo`. Отрицательное число в результате означает, что первая строка "меньше"; значение больше 0 - что первая строка "больше"; иначе - одинаковые.

```
String a = "abc", b = "acb";
int compare = a.compareTo(b);
  if(compare < 0) {
    print(a + " < " + b);
  } else if(compare > 0){
    print(a + " > " + b);
  } else {
    print(a + " == " + b);
  }
```

Вывод в этом случае: `abc < acb`

[Документация по методу compareTo()](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/dart-core/String/compareTo.html)

Comment: Спасибо не знал про него